# How do I capture the previous hour data from SQL table using python for every hour?

Tags: python, sql

Basically I have SQL table with Name, CustomerID, PurchaseDateTime column. And every hour I have a model that has to run based on these three columns in python that should fetch the previous hour data.

In python, the select script which I use to fetch the previous hour data is below, and this will be stored in Pandas dataframe and use it for the model.

```
def CustomerData():
    sql = "SELECT Name, CustomerID, PurchaseDateTime FROM XYZ table WHERE (PurchaseDateTime between '' and '')"
    DF = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
    DF.columns = ['Name', 'CustomerID', 'PurchaseDate']
    return DF
```

Every hour it should pick up the previous 1 hour data automatically without hardcording any values. For example, if my python model script runs at 4pm, I need a select script in such a way that all the transactions happened between 3-4pm should be pulled. Similarly this should happen every hour.

In case any delay happens due to X reasons and script triggers at 4.02 PM instead of 4pm. Then also my script should pick data from 3.00 PM and not from 3.02 PM.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to do:

```
def CustomerData():
    sql = "SELECT Name, CustomerID, PurchaseDateTime FROM XYZ table WHERE (PurchaseDateTime between CAST(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h'), ':00:00') AS DATETIME) and date_add(CAST(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h'), ':00:00') AS DATETIME),interval -1 hour))"
    DF = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
    DF.columns = ['Name', 'CustomerID', 'PurchaseDate']
    return DF
```

Comment: what if some delay happens due to some X reason and script triggers at 1.02 PM  instead of 1 PM?  It takes data from 1.02 PM to 12.02 PM. The 2 minutes of transaction data will not be considered then. I do not want that to happen.

Comment: OK, so in that case you will first have to truncate the now() timestamp to be  like '2020-05-18 13:00:00'

Comment: @hdhanarajan I already update the answer, take a look. That works for Mysql you may need to adapt it to you db

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, CustomerID, PurchaseDateTime FROM XYZ table
WHERE
(
    cast(getdate() as date)  = cast(PurchaseDateTime as date)
and DATEPART(HH,getdate()) =DATEPART(HH,PurchaseDateTime)+1
)
or 
    (
    DATEPART(HH,getdate()) = 1 and DATEPART(HH,PurchaseDateTime)=23
and cast(getdate() as date)  = cast(PurchaseDateTime as date)-1

    )
```

using the above sql code will get you the data of the last hour, ignoring any other smaller fractions